# Symfony reusable AJAX select / ChoiceType

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a reusable AJAX-based select ([select2](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)) using Symfony form types and I've spent quite some time on it but can't get it to work like I want.

As far as I know you cannot override options of form fields after they have been added, so you have to re-add them with the new config. The Symfony docs also provide some examples on how to dynamically add or modify forms using events. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

I've managed to create my AJAX based elements in the form and it's working but not completely reusable yet:

- Form field extends Doctrine EntityType to have full support of data mappers etc
- Form field is initialized with `'choices' => [],` so Doctrine does not load any entities from db
- Existing choices on edit is added during `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA`
- Posted choices are added during `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`

The current setup works **but only in the parent form**. I want to have my `AjaxNodeType` completely reusable so the parent form does not need to care about data handling and events.
Following the 2 examples, parent and child form. Here with event listeners in both, but of course they should only be in one.

**Is it simply not possible in single element types to replace "yourself" in the parent form or am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to dynamically change the choices?**

---

**Parent form**
This works!

```php
class MyResultElementType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'fixedNode',
                AjaxNodeType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Fixed node',
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            );

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (PreSetDataEvent $event) {
                if ($event->getData()) {
                    $fixedNode = $event->getData()->getFixedNode();

                    //this works here but not in child???
                    if ($fixedNode) {
                        $name = 'fixedNode';
                        $parentForm = $event->getForm();
                        $options = $parentForm->get($name)->getConfig()->getOptions();
                        $options['choices'] = [$fixedNode];
                        $parentForm->add($name, AjaxNodeType::class, $options);
                    }
                }
            },
            1000
        );


        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (PreSubmitEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData()['fixedNode'];
                if ($data) {
                    $name = 'fixedNode';
                    $parentForm = $event->getForm();

                    // we have to add the POST-ed data/node here to the choice list
                    // otherwise the submitted value is not valid
                    $node = $this->entityManager->find(Node::class, $data);
                    $options = $parentForm->get($name)->getConfig()->getOptions();
                    $options['choices'] = [$node];
                    $parentForm->add($name, AjaxNodeType::class, $options);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => MyResultElement::class,
                'method' => 'POST',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**Child form / single select** This does NOT work. On POST the `fixedNode` field is not set to the form data-entity.

```php
class AjaxNodeType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //this does not work here but in parent???
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (PreSetDataEvent $event) {
                if ($event->getData()) {
                    $fixedNode = $event->getData();

                    $name = $event->getForm()->getName();
                    $parentForm = $event->getForm()->getParent();
                    $options = $parentForm->get($name)->getConfig()->getOptions();
                    $newChoices = [$fixedNode];
                    // check if the choices already match, otherwise we'll end up in an endless loop ???
                    if ($options['choices'] !== $newChoices) {
                        $options['choices'] = $newChoices;
                        $parentForm->add($name, AjaxNodeType::class, $options);
                    }
                }
            },
            1000
        );

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (PreSubmitEvent $event) {
                if ($event->getData()) {
                    $name = $event->getForm()->getName();
                    $data = $event->getData();
                    $parentForm = $event->getForm()->getParent();

                    // we have to add the POST-ed data/node here to the choice list
                    // otherwise the submitted value is not valid
                    $node = $this->entityManager->find(Node::class, $data);
                    $options = $parentForm->get($name)->getConfig()->getOptions();
                    $options['choices'] = [$node];
                    $parentForm->add($name, self::class, $options);
                }
            },
            1000
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'class' => Node::class,
                // prevent doctrine from loading ALL nodes
                'choices' => [],
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, answering my own Questions :)
After spending some more time on it I got a working solution. And maybe it will be helpful for someone.

- I've switched from EntityType to ChoiceType as it only made things more complicated and is not actually needed
- multiple and single selects need different settings/workarrounds (like by_reference), see the line comments below
- re-adding yourself to the parent form works, I don't know why it did not before...
- beware of endless-loops when re-adding / re-submitting values

The main re-usable `AjaxEntityType` that does all the logic without reference to any specific entity:

```php
<?php

namespace Tool\Form\SingleInputs;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DataTransformer\CollectionToArrayTransformer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\EventListener\MergeDoctrineCollectionListener;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\PreSetDataEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\PreSubmitEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AjaxEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // shamelessly copied from DoctrineType - this is needed to support Doctrine Collections in multi-selects
        if ($options['multiple'] && interface_exists(Collection::class)) {
            $builder
                ->addEventSubscriber(new MergeDoctrineCollectionListener())
                ->addViewTransformer(new CollectionToArrayTransformer(), true);
        }

        // PRE_SET_DATA is the entrypoint on form creation where we need to populate existing choices
        // we process current data and set it as choices so it will be rendered correctly
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (PreSetDataEvent $event) use($options) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $hasData = ($options['multiple'] && count($data) > 0) || (!$options['multiple'] && $data !== null);
                if ($hasData) {
                    $entityOrList = $event->getData();

                    $name = $event->getForm()->getName();
                    $parentForm = $event->getForm()->getParent();
                    $options = $parentForm->get($name)->getConfig()->getOptions();

                    // ONLY do this if the choices are empty, otherwise readding PRE_SUBMIT will not work because this is called again!
                    if(empty($options['choices'])) {
                        if($options['multiple']) {
                            $newChoices = [];
                            foreach ($entityOrList as $item) {
                                $newChoices[$item->getId()] = $item;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $newChoices = [$entityOrList->getId() => $entityOrList];
                        }

                        $options['choices'] = $newChoices;
                        $parentForm->add($name, self::class, $options);
                    }
                }
            },
            1000
        );

        // PRE_SUBMIT is the entrypoint where we need to process the submitted values
        // we have to add the POST-ed choices, otherwise this field won't be valid
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (PreSubmitEvent $event) use($options)  {
            $entityIdOrList = $event->getData();
            $entityClass = $options['class'];

            // new choices constructed from POST
            $newChoices = [];

            if ($options['multiple']) {
                foreach ($entityIdOrList as $id) {
                    if ($id) {
                        $newChoices[$id] = $this->entityManager->find($entityClass, $id);
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($entityIdOrList) {
                $newChoices = [$entityIdOrList => $this->entityManager->find($entityClass, $entityIdOrList)];
            }

            $name = $event->getForm()->getName();
            $parentform = $event->getForm()->getParent();

            $currentChoices = $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOptions()['choices'];

            // if the user selected/posted new choices that have not been in the existing list, add them all
            if ($newChoices && count(array_diff($newChoices, $currentChoices)) > 0) {
                $options = $event->getForm()->getParent()->get($name)->getConfig()->getOptions();
                $options['choices'] = $newChoices;

                // re-add ourselves to the parent form with updated / POST-ed options
                $parentform->add($name, self::class, $options);
                if(!$parentform->get($name)->isSubmitted()) {
                    // after re-adding we also need to re-submit ourselves
                    $parentform->get($name)->submit($entityIdOrList);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'mapped' => true,
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'choice_label' => 'selectLabel',
                'choices' => [],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'select2-ajax',
                ],
                'ajax_url' => null,
            ]
        );

        // AJAX endpoint that is select2 compatible
        // https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax
        $resolver->setRequired('ajax_url');
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('ajax_url', ['string']);

        // entity class to process
        $resolver->setRequired('class');

        // by_reference needs to be true for single-selects, otherwise our entities will be cloned!
        // by_reference needs to be false for multi-selects, otherwise the setters wont be called for doctrine collections!
        $resolver->setDefault('by_reference', function (Options $options) {
            return !$options['multiple'];
        });

        // adds the ajax_url as attribute
        $resolver->setNormalizer('attr', function (Options $options, $value) {
            $value['data-custom-ajax-url'] = $options['ajax_url'];

            return $value;
        });
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

Actual usage with specific entity and ajax endpoint:

```php
<?php

namespace Tool\Form\SingleInputs;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Tool\Entities\User\Node;

class AjaxNodeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'class' => Node::class,
                'ajax_url' => 's/ajax-select/nodes',
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return AjaxEntityType::class;
    }
}
```